# Issue with Windows Service: Windows Service not displayed in list of Services even after installation

Tags: .net, windows-services

I am a newbie into Windows Service

I have installed my Windows service using `installutil` command.

Now it shows that installation is successful but when I try to access the service from

```
 ControlPanel->Administrative Tools->Computer Management->Services and Applications->Services
```

But I am not able to see my windows service in the list of services.

Where should I look for it?

**Screenshot of Installation of Windows Service:**

This is the message that is displayed after installation of windows service. I hope that it means that Windows Service is installed successfully

[image]

If installation is successful then what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might not have added an installer to your service. You need to make sure you have:

- An [Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx).
- A [ServiceInstaller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.aspx).
- A [ServiceProcessInstaller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceprocessinstaller.aspx).

Wire them together [like this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/simplewindowsservice.aspx#premain5).

Comment: I have added them all into my project and wired them still the problem persists

Comment: Yeah I am running it as an admin.